# How do I turn a hash which looks like this { { { } } } into one that looks like this { { [ ] } }?

Tags: ruby, hash, nokogiri

So this is the code I'm using:

```
  @department_hash = {}
  department.css('li').each do | department |
    department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
    department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/]
    @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
    @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= {}
    @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"][department_title] = department_count
  end
```

Which produces something like this:

> {:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{""=>nil, "Birds"=>"15,863",
>   "Cats"=>"243,396", "Dogs"=>"512,965", "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>"46,428",
>   "Horses"=>"14,738", "Insects"=>"360", "Reptiles &
>   Amphibians"=>"5,843", "Small Animals"=>"19,871"}}}

But what I want is to produce something like this:

> {:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>[""=>nil, "Birds"=>"15,863",
>   "Cats"=>"243,396", "Dogs"=>"512,965", "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>"46,428",
>   "Horses"=>"14,738", "Insects"=>"360", "Reptiles &
>   Amphibians"=>"5,843", "Small Animals"=>"19,871"]}}

How do I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

How about this? Is this valid ruby code?

```
departments: { "Pet Supplies": [ "Birds" : 16651, "Cats" : 242910, etc ] }
```

Comment: You can't. `[]` is for arrays, `{}` is for hashes, which is what you still have in your second example.

Comment: That is not a valid Ruby code.

Comment: @alexchenco *"Is this valid ruby code?"* - No, it's not, copy and paste it in `irb` and you'll get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The best you can do is something like this:

```
{ foo: [ { key: :value }, { key: :value } ] }
```

To do so:

```
@department_hash = {}
  department.css('li').each do | department |
    department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
    department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/]
    @department_hash[:department] ||= {}
    @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] ||= []
    @department_hash[:department]["Pet Supplies"] << { key: :value } # replace with your own hash
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How about my **EDIT** is that valid Ruby code?

Comment: No, you need a hash to do stuff like `'foo' : 123`. In ruby it looks like `{ foo: 123 }`. Then wrap it into an array: `[{ foo: 123 }]`